# Can we use @RepeatedTest along with @ParameterizedTest in Junit 5

Tags: junit5

Currently, I'm (attempting to) migrate existing Junit4 Project to Junit5.

I'm stuck in a place where I have to use both @RepeatedTest and @ParameterizedTest.
Attempting this throws the default exception - `No Runnable Methods found`

As an alternative, I should be able to pass Parameters to each of my test from two different sources - which ends up in `Null` values for the second source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use `@RepeatedTest` and `@ParameterizedTest` on the same method since both are implementations of a `@TestTemplate`, and a method can have only one *test template*. See [JUnit 5 issue #1224](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1224) for details.

Note, however, that JUnit Jupiter will eventually support *container templates*. See [JUnit 5 issue #871](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/871) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any recommendation on how to solve my issue.!

Comment: Will it help me to fix the issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78035461/how-to-replace-parameterizedtest-with-retryingtest