# How to replace @ParameterizedTest with RetryingTest?

Tags: java, kotlin, junit5, retry-logic, junit-pioneer

I have a test:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getTestData")
fun fooTest(
    arg1: Int,
    arg2: Int,
    arg3: String,
) { 
    ...
```

It communicates with quite unstable test container (I can't make it more stable).

So from time to time it fails

Based on [this](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/retrying-test/)

I've added dependency:

```
testImplementation("org.junit-pioneer:junit-pioneer:2.2.0")
```

and rewrote it it with:

```
@RetryingTest(maxAttempts = 3, minSuccess = 1, suspendForMs = 1000)
@MethodSource("getTestData")
fun fooTest(
    arg1: Int,
    arg2: Int,
    arg3: String,
) { 
    ...
```

but looks like it doesn't see `@MethodSource` annotation:

```
Test execution #3 (of up to 3 with at least 1 successes) failed ~> test fails - see cause for details (2 failures)
    org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [int arg1] in method ...
Test execution #1 (of up to 3) failed ~> will retry in 1000 ms...
    org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [int arg1] in method ...
Test execution #2 (of up to 3) failed ~> will retry in 1000 ms...
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException: Test execution #3 (of up to 3 with at least 1 successes) failed ~> test fails - see cause for details (2 failures)
    org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [int arg1] in method ...
Test execution #1 (of up to 3) failed ~> will retry in 1000 ms...
    org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [int arg1] in method ....
Test execution #2 (of up to 3) failed ~> will retry in 1000 ms..
```

.

Is there way to fix it ?

**P.S.** I've found [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71887058/how-can-i-retry-a-parameterized-test-on-junit-5) but there are no **correct** answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Looks like it is impossible with `@RetryingTest`

https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer/issues/355

https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer/issues/405